# fail to kinit from windows 10 to kerberos server rhel 7 in bash/cmd

Tags: cmd, windows-10, kerberos, rhel7, hdp

I want to get access to my server which secured with kerberos
I've tried some similar step to configure kerberos client in windows such as in;https://mapr.com/docs/61/Impala/configuring_kerberos_authentication_for_windows.html or https://www.simba.com/products/Hive/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/hi/kerberos.htm

1. I've install the MIT Kerberos (for windows client)
2. I've set environment variable KRB5CCNAME in (e:\kerberized\temp\krb5_cc_cache
3. I've tried to config krb5.ini in C:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5 such as below

   ```
   [libdefaults]
     default_realm = DCDMS.LOC
     renew_lifetime = 7d
     forwardable = true  
     ticket_lifetime = 24h
     dns_lookup_realm = true
     dns_lookup_kdc = false
     default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
     #default_tgs_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5
     #default_tkt_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5

   [domain_realm]
     .dcdms.loc = DCDMS.LOC
     dcdms.loc = DCDMS.LOC

   [logging]
     default = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
     admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
     kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log

   [realms]
     DCDMS.LOC = {
       admin_server = admhdop.dcdms
       kdc = admhdop.dcdms
       master_kdc = admhdop.dcdms
     }
   ```
4. Then I've configure in hosts file such as below

   ```
   10.0.37.231     admhdop.dcdms   admhdop admhdop.dcdms.loc dcdms.loc
   10.0.45.11      mghdop01.dcdms  mghdop01
   ```
5. Then we try to

   ```
   kinit -kt e:\kerberized\hive2.keytab hdfs@DCDMS.LOC
   ```

   but it returns

> kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm "DCDMS.LOC" while getting initial
>   credentials

6. Then we try to

   ```
   kinit -kt hdfs@DCDMS.LOC
   ```

and it returns

> kinit: Cannot determine realm for host (principal host/.......)

Is there any step that missed?

Note: the krb5.ini in that placed in windows is downloaded from linux client that succesfully access the server that secured by kerberos

-Thanks-

Comment: Look at your [realms] section.  Is that one of your internal domain names - admhdop.dcdms?

Comment: Which `kinit.exe` do you use? One provided by Microsoft, one provided by MIT Kerberos, one provided by Java? Did you set env variable `KRB5_CONFIG` to point explicitly to your `krb5.ini` file? Did you carefully read the MIT Kerberos documentation _(the general doc, not just for the Windows utility)_? BTW, did you try to create a ticket with the GUI?

Comment: @T-Heron I think it's already the internal domain names where kerberos system implemented (it's in HDP kerberized server), or how I can check the internal domain names?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter kinit.exe in my windows? it's from mit site. I'll try the set KRB5_CONFIG env. For the ticket, I just re-use the keytab that have been created in HDP server

Comment: I repeat my question, because you did not answer it:  did you try to create a **ticket** with the **GUI**? I.e. open the MIT-Kerberos-for-Windows GUI and enter principal/ **password** ?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: I didn't try to create ticket with the GUI, because I suggested by the HDP kerberized admin just to use the keytab that has been created in HDP kerberized server

Comment: So you don't want to try something different, to understand where the problem comes from. All right, it's your choice. Good luck.